# Is it possible to have multiple citations in parentheses with page numbers using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I need to have page numbers on all my citations and I don't know how to do it. I don't seem to find any answers on this question.

I have tried

```
\parencites{[231]{tversky1973availability}[1130-1131]{tversky1974judgment}[263]{kahneman1979prospect}[38]{ackert2010behavioral}}
```

but that gives me an error.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had misplaced the parentheses. If I use

```
\parencites[231]{tversky1973availability}[1130-1131]{tversky1974judgment}[263]{kahneman1979prospect}[38]{ackert2010behavioral}
```

everything works.

Comment: You can accept own answer. Do this!